# java + SQLite project. Foreign key "On Update" not updating

Tags: java, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am making a javafx (intelliJ with java jdk 11) app using SQLite version 3.30.1 with DB Browser for SQLite.
I have a table called "beehives" and each beehive can have diseases (stored in the table "diseases").
this is my "beehives" table:

```
CREATE TABLE "beehives" (
"number"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"id_apiary" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -2,
"date"  DATE,
"type"  TEXT,
"favorite"  BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false',
PRIMARY KEY("number","id_apiary"),
FOREIGN KEY("id_apiary") REFERENCES "apiaries"("id") ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

this is my "diseases" table:

```
CREATE TABLE "diseases" (
"id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"id_beehive"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"id_apiary" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"disease"   TEXT NOT NULL,
"treatment" TEXT NOT NULL,
"start_treat_date"  DATE NOT NULL,
"end_treat_date"    DATE,
PRIMARY KEY("id"),
FOREIGN KEY("id_beehive","id_apiary") REFERENCES "beehives"("number","id_apiary") ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

this is my "apiaries" table in case you need it:

```
CREATE TABLE "apiaries" (
"id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
"name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
"address"   TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

Everything works fine, but when I update a beehive (for example when I update the "number", which is the primary key in beehives table) the diseases does not update the number. The result is that the diseases get some kind of disconnected since the beehive change his "number" correctly, but the disease doesn't update it. There is no error message.
My java method that calls the update is:

```
    public void updateBeehiveInDB(Beehives newBeehive,Beehives oldBeehive){        

    try {

        s = "UPDATE beehives SET number=?, id_apiary=?, date=?, type=?, favorite=? WHERE number=? and id_apiary=? ";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(s);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, newBeehive.getNumber());
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, newBeehive.getId_apiary());
        preparedStatement.setDate(3, newBeehive.getDate());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, newBeehive.getType());
        preparedStatement.setBoolean(5, newBeehive.isFavorite());
        preparedStatement.setInt(6, oldBeehive.getNumber());
        preparedStatement.setInt(7,oldBeehive.getId_apiary());

        int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried to check if foreign keys are "on" following the SQLite documentation [here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), but my English is not good enough and I am using DB Manager. So no idea how to check if this is on, or how to turn it on manually.

What can I do to update the diseases "id_beehives" when I update "number" on beehives table?

Comment: that's unrelated to fx - first solve the db issue in isolation, then do the next step and include into a ui :)

Comment: You need to enable foreign keys in your java program every time you open the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i am using a composite foreign key and i need to implement it correctly on other tables too even if i was not using them yet in this new project. Was very hard to find the problem because intellij normally show all the SQL error messages, but in this case, it was not showing anything. But when i tried to do the SQL sentence manually in the DB Browser, there i got an error message and was able to fix it.

Also had to activate foreign key on the connection:

```
   public Connection openConnection() {

    try {

        String dbPath = "jdbc:sqlite:resources/db/datab.db";
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
        config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath,config.toProperties());

        return connection;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```